# Saving SQLite Database to specific File

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite

**Introduction**

I am using the official [sqlite NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite/) (3.13.0) and [entity framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) (6.2.0). My initial [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/) is `data source=sample-database.sqlite`.

**My Question**

How can I save the complete database to a different file (e.g. `D:\Path\To\NewFile.sqlite`)? I just can think of copying the database file to the new location and renaming it, but this solution feels kind of weird.

Thank you. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `sqlite` connection strings support absolute paths. What's your problem?

Comment: When I change the connectionstring to another path, the data won't be copied and a new database will be created at the specified location. How do I copy the whole data to ```D:\Path\To\NewFile.sqlite```?

Comment: Right click the file and hit rename? Or if you need to do it programatically, File.Move?  I don't know what you mean by "feels kind of weird". SQLite databases are merely files on disc - you manage them like you would any other file.

Comment: Keep it simple. There's nothing wrong going manual way i.e. move db > rename > change connection string in app.

Comment: Okay, I got it. You convinced me =) Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I save the complete database to a different file (e.g.
>   D:\Path\To\NewFile.sqlite)? I just can think of copying the database
>   file to the new location and renaming it, **but this solution feels kind
>   of weird.**

Nope. Not weird. I have done this and it works just fine. Just need to remember that you may need to be aware of the new DB location when you add another migration + update-database, (if the connection string is defined in various places)